# Is there a way I can find all my questions on all stackexchange sites in one place?

Tags: feature-request

Right now I have to bookmark the specific sites. Then visit them and go to my profile to check on the questions. It is not just about responding to an answer. Sometimes I may have something to report back later but it becomes tedious.

The way I find all the sites at StackExchange I am a member of is by clicking on my user id at the top and clicking on the accounts tab. I wish there was a tab for "my questions".

Comment: I believe there was a suggestion at some point to have cross-site notifications

Comment: It would be great to have an aggreagate site for all my stack exchange sites. I  would like to be able to select User Interface, Stack Overflow, Cooking and Gaming for instance. Then have the ability to search, etc.  When asking a question an extra field would be required to select the site you want to post it on.  Posting a question to multiple sites would not be allowed.

Comment: This is becoming an issue for me as I am now a member of around 20 SE sites, so I need to know which questions I have not marked answers on in one place instead of having to log into each site...

Answer (score 1):

This is the closest thing I can offer:

http://stackcenter.quickmediasolutions.com

*Feedback is welcome.*

Comment: Don't know where you expect feedback to go so I'll throw it in a comment. SE2.0 Meta reputation is counted as equivalent to your reputation on the parent site, and that appears to be double-calculated in the "total reputation" on the side. I recommend you don't calculate it.

Comment: @Grace: Oh yeah... I never thought of that. It also ignores Area51 rep. I plan to fix both.

Comment: Thanks. I am interested in the content I am associated with than just the reputation though :)

Comment: @Grace: The Meta-miscalculation has now been fixed.

Comment: @James: I am planning to add more as time permits.