# Is there a way to list all the Stack Exchange sites that a user is linked to (in the drop down)?

Tags: feature-request

The StackExchange dropdown in the header list Hot Questions, All Sites and Inbox.

It would be a nice feature have the sites that I have linked listed (the sites that are associated with my id) as a dropdown ([in the same vein as this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60573/is-there-a-way-i-can-find-all-my-questions-on-all-stackexchange-sites-in-one-plac))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "All Sites" part of the dropdown is partially sorted by the reputation you have on the sites. The sites where you have over 200 reputation will be at the top, ordered by your reputation. You can quickly switch between your top sites that way.

Comment: Well, if it can be partially sorted, then it stands to reason that that it can be fully sorted (ive seen that feature request) and further sorted with the sites that I am actually subscribed.  Just a feature request to add the tab since the data is there...

Comment: @Stuart Given the current sorting, I'm not sure what your feature request adds that doesn't already exist.

Comment: I think the issue is that 200 is a rather high bar, especially on the smaller sites.  So it ends up being the one site where you have 200+, and then all the rest, so not that useful.  Why not list all sites where you have non-zero rep first?

Comment: @Smackfu,  non zero reps at the top is a perfect solution.  This would do it for me!

Answer (score 3):

That information is available on your profile:

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/163099/stuart-siegler?tab=accounts

Comment: Not exactly.  That's the list.  I'm hoping to have it populated in the menu bar dropdown so its quick-selectable (so I can jump from site to site)

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean `URL_TO_PROFILE?tab=accounts`? Like [octavian-damiean?tab=accounts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/151013/octavian-damiean?tab=accounts)

Answer (score 0):

The Stack Exchange drop-down menu (a.k.a. the Super-collider drop-down menu) shows the list of the SE sites basing on your reputation, where the site on which your reputation is higher is shown on the top. If you have a high reputation on a site, it means you visit that site more frequently than others.
Having another drop-down menu that lists the sites where you have an account would partially duplicate the Stack Exchange menu. It would probably better to change the existing drop-down menu by changing the criteria used to sort the list of SE sites.

[image: screenshot]