# Indicator for sites you have an account on in the "all sites" list

Tags: feature-request, stack-exchange-button

In the *all sites* list, could we please have an indicator if the you have an account on a given site or not? The list is already [partially sorted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/95506/133217) based on which accounts the user have, so the information is already available for use when making the list. In my mind that means that putting a indicator of account or not should be relative simple.

That would be extremely valuable, so I could see which sites I do not have an account on. I am aware of https://stackexchange.com/users/...?tab=accounts, however that does not address the issue of showing which sites I do not have an account on (without lots of manual labour).

Comment: Hm, why would it be "extremely valuable" to know on which sites you do not have an account?

Comment: Because there are new sites created all the time. I have created accounts on most of them, leaving out sites I have no interest in. Even if I go through the site list from time to time to check if there seem to be some new interesting site to join (which I do from time to time), I have a hard time remembering if I have created an account or not on absolutely all sites, and manually opening each site just to check is way to much work. With an "I already have an account" indicator this would be much better.

Answer (score 3):

Interesting idea. Won't be *extremely* valuable, but nice to have.

I will make it consistent with the [badges page](https://stackoverflow.com/badges) where you have green checkmark beside badges you already won, and apply it in the [main sites list](https://stackexchange.com/sites) not the  Stack Exchange™ MultiCollider SuperDropdown™. Rough sketch would be:

> [image]

With tooltip saying you already have account on that site and maybe even for how long.

Comment: This sounds good.